# Filters are missing from Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on CodePen and included Fabric.js in JavaScript settings.
CodePen automatically bought version 2.4.4 for me:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.4/fabric.min.js

When I am trying to use for example the Tint filter, I am getting `its not a constructor` error in browser console.

But, the Tint filter is already available in the Fabric.js docs: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.Tint.html

I also did: `console.log(fabric.Image.filters);` and the output is:

```
BaseFilter: ƒ i(), 
BlackWhite: ƒ i(), 
BlendColor: ƒ i(), 
BlendImage: ƒ i(), 
Blur: ƒ i(), 
Brightness: ƒ i(), 
Brownie: ƒ i(), 
ColorMatrix: ƒ i(), 
Composed: ƒ i(), 
Contrast: ƒ i(), 
Convolute: ƒ i(), 
Gamma: ƒ i(), 
Grayscale: ƒ i(), 
HueRotation: ƒ i(), 
Invert: ƒ i(), 
Kodachrome: ƒ i(), 
Noise: ƒ i(), 
Pixelate: ƒ i(), 
Polaroid: ƒ i(), 
RemoveColor: ƒ i(), 
Resize: ƒ i(), 
Saturation: ƒ i(), 
Sepia: ƒ i(), 
Technicolor: ƒ i(), 
Vintage: ƒ i()
```

As you can see Tint filter is not even available in filters.

Also, tried to use a version from fabricjs.com itself, using the download link at the bottom (Download version 2.4.3): http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.min.js

But, this version also has the same problem.

Comment: try to add the tint code manually right after fabric, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/60e9d0f144582433bcdc7c452c2140b0452905c4/src/filters/tint_filter.class.js

Comment: @kobe: Thanks, but what I want to know is that why all classes are not included in `fabric.min.js`. Documentation is also not clear about it and it is not stated that classes should be included separately. I do not want to do any temporary workaround for this.

Comment: you right, i posted the right answer with no hacks

Comment: @kobe: Thanks, yes this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And i've opened an issue at github to update docs: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some investigation to find where's tint filter gone.
look at the commit: 
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/commit/e96ccf9ea64df529cbbbea869561a5a8da2cf1ac#diff-92d93b4f6664e4db62af0f12768dfe56R39

Tint isn't gone, but the code has changed, to use tint filter you should write:

`var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
  color: 'red',
  mode: 'tint',
  alpha: 0.5
});`

Comment: The code example toke from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702213/fabric-js-blendcolor-image-filter